# JavaScript Rotate

Tags: javascript

I need to rotate an image before loading it into a canvas.
As far as I know, I cant rotate it using the canvas.rotate(), since that rotates the entire scene.

Is there a good JS way to rotate an image?  [not the browser dependent ways]

Comment: You can rotate it in CSS - http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1004-how-to-rotate-an-image-with-css/

Comment: Yeah, but thats a browser dependent way. I'm looking for a javascript way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not exactly, you can save the scene, rotate image then restore scene:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 600; 
canvas.height = 400; 
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'https://www.google.ro/images/srpr/logo3w.png';
drawRotatedImage(image, 275, 95, 25); 

function drawRotatedImage(image, x, y, angle) { 
    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.rotate(angle * (Math.PI/180));
    ctx.drawImage(image, -(image.width/2), -(image.height/2));
    ctx.restore(); 
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fEFKK/)

Answer (score 0):

well for u can use a css property transform to rotate, scale and translate  html elements instead of using canvas for this you should use transform="rotate(xdeg)" if you want to rotate the image x degrees for continuously rotating the image use the following code. 
see this your code

```
<html>
<img id="t1" src="1.png">
</html>
and this is your javascript code
<script>
    var im;
    var w,h;
    var t=0;
    window.onload=function()
    {
     im=document.getElementById('t1');
     w=im.width;
     h=im.height;
         im.style.transform=im.style.webkitTransform|im.style.mozTransform|im.style.oTransform|i     m.style.transform;
     update();
    };
    function update()
    {

     im.style.transform="rotate("+t+"deg)";
     t+=10;
     setTimeout("update()",100);
    }
</script>
```